# Split and append

Tags: python

- Input:- A89456FRERT120108A.1

  Output expected:- 120108AT.1

I am thinking of the below ...can anyone help me if there is an easier way to achieve this, I  need to append "T" for the alphanumeric character

1. Split based on "."

   Get the alphanumeric character for `split[0]` once the first digit is encountered (which is "120108A" in this case)

   Append "T" to #2 (it will be 120108AT)

   Then put back `split[1]` (120108AT.1)

Comment: This might be a case for regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a regex solution, which attempts to use the same logic that you provided:

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(r'^.*?(\d+\D*)(\..*)', r'\1T\2', orig_string)
```

Example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^.*?(\d+\D*)(\..*)', r'\1T\2', 'A89456FRERT120108A.1')
'120108AT.1'
```

Explanation:

```
#regex:
    ^            # match at the start of the string
    .*?          # match any number of any character (as few as possible)
    (            # start capture group 1
      \d+          # match one or more digits
      \D*          # match any number of non-digits
    )            # end capture group 1
    (            # start capture group 2
      \..*         # match a '.', then match to the end of the string
    )            # end capture group 2

#replacement
    \1           # contents of first capture group (from digits up to the '.')
    T            # literal 'T'
    \2           # contents of second capture group ('.' to end of string)
```